# How to use GET method in Expressjs

Tags: html, node.js, express

Person, I have a folder called "vehicles" on my PC, and I want to create a localhost to create a link for each image of that.

Example:

localhost: 800 / vehicle / <name of the .png file>

For when I access the link, I return the image.

However, I am new ... I would like to assist you in how I can do this.

I did some things but always return to 404 not found error status.

tentative code:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let img = `<img src="./vehicles/150.png"/>`;
  let html = `<!Doctype html><html><head><title>Sample</title></head>`;
  html += `<body><main>${img}</main></body></html>`;
  res.send(html);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

[image]

I'm a beginner, I would like to know how I can do this ...

Comment: Already tried:

let img = `<img src ="/vehicles/150.png "/>`;

But without success

Comment: You've specified that `public` folder is used for static content, but you don't have it in your project root directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can place thats files in folder named "public/vehicles" and then express will do everythig for you.

Folder public is place for sharing files like js, css and images etc.

Comment: I'm a beginner.

Could you show me an example of how to do it?

Comment: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: Sorry guys, but I still don't understand how I can do it.

Could someone present the code completely?

Comment: Its easy you enter that code in to your app and then create folder named as public and then place there folder vehicles

Comment: I tried to do this, but it is giving me error on localhost

Comment: in your case app means localhost.js file

Comment: Browser: localhost status (failed)

Comment: remove 5 line or change 'public' in it to path.join(__dirname, 'public'

Comment: Stayed:

app.use(express.static('public/vehicles'))

let img = `<img src="/150.png"/>`;

Comment: and i forget for install path [npm i path] and create const of it const path = require('path');

Comment: Localhost status(failed)

Comment: I  don't know what is it. Maybe i can help you via meet?